# DataFrame больше не отправляется в BigQuery с помощью pandas_gbq.to_gbq

Tags: python, dataframe, bigquery

Долгое время отправлял в BigQuery DataFrame с помощью такого кода:

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(file, 'keys.clientnum', project_id='red-abstraction-999999',if_exists='replace')
```

Сегодня же что-то обновилось, и выдается ошибка

[image: Ошибка]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как этого можно избежать.
Обычное добавление прогресс-бара не помогло

Структура данных:

CampaignName -                object

Impressions   -                int64

Clicks    -                    int64

Ctr     -                    float64

Cost    -                    float64

AvgCpc    -                  float64

BounceRate    -              float64

AvgPageviews       -         float64

ConversionRate     -         float64

CostPerConversion    -       float64

Conversions      -             int64

Date       -          datetime64[ns]

Bounce_clicks        -       float64

dtype: object

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку выдаёт библиотека `tqdm`, которая вызывается в библиотеке `pandas_gbq`. Решение проблемы будет зависеть от того, как выглядит ваша экосистема `Python`. Если вы сами ставите бибилиотеки - попробуйте разные версии `tqdm`, надо найти версию, совместимую с вашей текущей версией библиотеки `pandas_gbq`. Возможно, достаточно будет просто обновить библиотеку `tqdm` до свежей версии.
Но лучше, конечно, пользоваться стабильными окружениями, где все библиотеки между собой проверены и согласованы, например `Anaconda`.